# Extract data of last 5 days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need help here, I am trying to extract the data of last 5 days, but I always end up with an error.

Data

```
Data_Date     A
2021-03-11  1145942
2021-03-12  1105853
2021-03-13  2101335
2021-03-14  1640319
2021-03-15  1584698
2021-03-16  1516285
2021-03-17  2822152
2021-03-18  2186634
2021-03-19  1136144
```

Code

```
today = pd.datetime.today().date()

df = df['Data_Date']

df['Data_Date'] = df[today - pd.offsets.Day(5):]
```

Error

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [2021-03-17 00:00:00] of <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need last 5 days before today use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['Data_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data_Date'])

today = pd.to_datetime('today').normalize()

mask = df['Data_Date'].between(today - pd.offsets.Day(5), today)

df = df[mask]
print (df)
   Data_Date        A
6 2021-03-17  2822152
7 2021-03-18  2186634
8 2021-03-19  1136144
```

Or if don need inclusive filter (`>` and `<`):

```
df['Data_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data_Date'])

today = pd.to_datetime('today').normalize()

mask = df['Data_Date'].between(today - pd.offsets.Day(5), today, inclusive=False)

df = df[mask]
print (df)
   Data_Date        A
7 2021-03-18  2186634
8 2021-03-19  1136144
```

But if need compare for `>` or `>=` change mask to:

```
mask = df['Data_Date'] > today - pd.offsets.Day(5)
mask = df['Data_Date'] >= today - pd.offsets.Day(5)

df = df[mask]
```